# Swift UIImageView inside UIStackView with unwanted padding

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, padding

I have a tedious problem.

I create a `ContainerView` that is embed with a `UIStackView`.

Inside this stack view I insert through the method "addArrangedSubview" several `UIView` that execute this line of code "NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed". One of this `UIView` has inside a NIB that has inside it an `UIImageView` that cover all the space and does not have margins. The image is loaded with the Kingfisher library with an URL.

The problem is the following:
[image: My Problem]

How can I remove that white spaces?

EDIT: The UIImageView has Aspect Fit proprerty. If I choose Scale To Fill the padding disappear. Then I understand that the view is drawn before the application of Aspect Fit. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Can you delineate the bounds of the stack view more clearly? Aspect Fit stops stretching content when it meets either vertical or horizontal bounds.